# Restauranting (?)

Tags: confusables

I think a new word could be developed relating to the action of running a restaurant or restaurants. In Portuguese, French and in English as well, I believe, the word restauracao, restauration is too easily confused with construction restoration. It doesn't even sound right. I would suggest restauranting for the action of running restaurants or the lifestyle of frequenting restaurants, for example, or as well. Restauranteur in absolute lieu of restaurateur, even though I understand both are acceptable.

Comment: [restauranteering](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/restauranteering)

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you're too late.  The word "restauranting" has been co-opted by foodies who go restaurant hopping and then blog about their experiences.  Go [here](http://www.mightysweet.com/mesohungry/category/restauranting/).  Or [here](https://mandydegeit.wordpress.com/about/) for the blogger who calls her writing "RestaurRanting."

Comment: Thanks. Late? To me, late is if you never show up. I checked out both links. Nice. Thank you kindly. I just dislike the word "restauration". I had never heard of it, until someone one day told me they into 'restauration', and I thought he had meant he was into restoration of buildings, etc, related to construction. 'Stevesliva' shows that 'restauranteering' exists to this effect, and I find it much more... refined. Thank you kindly for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

*restauranter* already exists and is a synonym of *restaurator*, according to Merriam-Webster.

Even if it didn't exist yet, creating a new word and causing it to be frequently used is not that simple. For a new word to emerge, that word would first need to become used by many people. You can't just force the creation of a new word like this. A need for a new word is required first.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your comment Mr. Sander. 'stevesliva' has posted that 'restauranteering' is a word according to Wiktionary. Correct? It's a more appealing word to me when describing "The act, or profession, of running a restaurant".Cheers.